# Jasper Report Gouping doesnt work for subreport data

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a MAIN report and then a subreport that it is given the data from the MAIN report like this:

```
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="224" uuid="b72a4572-ac0d-4a54-b57e-86e0420d1d94"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{sortedPositions})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["/storage/intranet/balancing/templates/INVOICE_POSITIONS_PICASSO_TEMPLATE.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
```

sortedPositions has the following fields

- id
- quantity
- value
- description
- corridor
- ProductConfiguration productConfiguration (another class)

When i try to group by any of the sortedPositions fileds the grouping doesn't work.
When i tried to book from the productConfiguration.field the grouping works!

The problem i that the field on which i want to group by is not in the productConfiguration and getting it directly from the sortedPositions doesn;t group as expected.

Here is the xml:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="INVOICE_POSITIONS_PICASSO_TEMPLATE" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="2e9314a9-2d41-428a-91e9-63a890b65110">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.6105100000000019"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<field name="quantity" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.Long"/>
<field name="value" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="corridor" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[productConfiguration.invoicePositionList.get(0).corridor]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="description" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="productName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[productConfiguration.product.name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="invoiceConfigurationId" class="java.lang.Long">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[productConfiguration.invoiceConfiguration.id]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="productDescription" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[productConfiguration.description]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="productConfigId" class="java.lang.Long">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[productConfiguration.id]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="period" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[invoice.period]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<variable name="sumValueFinal" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="ProductGroup" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}.abs()]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<group name="ProductGroup">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{corridor}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="58">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="37" width="455" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="87ce8c73-7c58-4775-87e4-307521c9f0fe"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    <paragraph rightIndent="2"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Subtotal:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="460" y="37" width="95" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="5456221b-3dee-46fc-a9a4-999da7067898"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph rightIndent="2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumValueFinal}.abs()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="8" width="45" height="20" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="e3207aed-06dc-4e00-9eac-adab729b841b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    <paragraph rightIndent="2"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[GROUP FINAL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="45" y="8" width="102" height="20" backcolor="#99FF99" uuid="e26a9f2a-b3c1-44df-b088-29f42dfea069"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph rightIndent="2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{productName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="455" y="8" width="95" height="20" backcolor="#99FF99" uuid="e1f7c353-c700-4d8a-9aa8-1c17c2c94743"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph rightIndent="2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}.abs()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="265" y="8" width="95" height="20" backcolor="#99FF99" uuid="7c9b2c7f-22c9-492f-a103-8047690a0080"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph rightIndent="2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{corridor}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="360" y="8" width="95" height="20" backcolor="#99FF99" uuid="351f7355-61aa-4c38-a2e7-1250f965f2eb"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph rightIndent="2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}.abs()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="147" y="8" width="102" height="20" backcolor="#99FF99" uuid="3a2a9adb-2873-43e2-b8f5-48e3df353572"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph rightIndent="2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
```

For reference the **description -> NOT group correctly**   on the other hand the **productDescription -> group correctly**!

Comment: As per [this grouping doc](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups), the data needs to be already sorted by the grouping value.  Does it work property if you add `<sortField name="corridor"/>`?

Comment: @dada67  Nope, it doesn't work. Attribute 'class' is not allowed to appear in element 'sortField'.

Comment: What exactly did you add in the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the sortedPosition that i was "feeding" to the subreport wasn't properly and correctly sorted! Be careful the jasper group only makes **one** iteration through the data and the dataSource that you use for grouping should be sorted according what you want to group.